# Custom use effect comparator : ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-ref

I am having a state variable that is defined as follows

```
  const [val, setVal] = useState({ notdone: [], done: [] })
```

where `done` has the following structure

```
[ { col: "val1", field: "val1", values: [1,2,3]}, { col: "val2", filed: "val2", values:[]  }
```

I want to run the useffect when some changes are made to the `done` and also `values` array under each object. In my case, useEffect gets triggered when I remove/add an objects to the `done`. But not when some changes happen inside `values` array of each object.

How can I have a watch on both the changes

```
useEffect(() => {
    callback();
 }, [val.done.length]);
```

It is achievable using `use-deep-compare-effect`, but is there a way to do this without using this external package?

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the outer array length alone isn't a strong enough comparison. The best counter-example against it is an array mutation where an element is removed while another is added, the result is an array of the same length.

React's `Object.is` equality check also doesn't do the deep equality check you seek.

The only way I know of to do this without an external dependency is a bit of a hack, but it works, is to JSON stringify* the array so a full string comparison is used.

```
useEffect(() => {
  callback();
}, [JSON.stringify(val.done)]);
```

* Source is basically a [twitter](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1104414469629898754) conversation from Dan Abramov

> Deep equality checks are generally a bad idea. If the inputs are
> shallow enough that you think deep equality would still be fast,
> consider just using [JSON.stringify(obj)] instead. Note it won’t
> compare functions.

Comment: thanks for the answer, Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: @li97 If you do a little googling you can find other "home-grown" `useDeepEqualityEffect` recipes out there.